# microsoft owin 3.0 claim for facebook and google

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, katana

i would like to know whether the claim in 3.00 update for
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook and Google support the latest API

Details:
Will Owin Security Facebook support graph API v2.0+ after April 30, 2015 as Facebook graph API v1.0 will be completely removed at that time. To make it more specific, can we still retrieve the name using urn:facebook:name after April 30, 2015 with the v3.00 update?

Similar case for Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google since Google has migrated the login from Google to Google+.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that the vendors would be able to answer based on projections in their plans.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer as I'm getting some unsightly warnings showing up in the Facebook auth prompt to users.

Answer (score 0):

https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/363

No need to do anything, automatic redirects in place at Facebook's end. You may want to read the thread linked above to understand if you have anything that will break. The warning message is only shown to app administrators.